# react-native-web update: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: react-native, dependencies, typeerror, updates, react-native-web

Note: My application compiles and runs smoothly with "react-native-web": "^0.11.*" in my ../common/package.json dependencies.

--

**CHANGES**

*updating ../common/package.json -> **"react-native-web": "^0.11.*"** to **"react-native-web": "^0.17.*"***

After restarting process (clean, install, build) the application now shows this error on start:

**ERRORS**

TypeError: **Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**

*../common/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/Router.js*

```
244 | ...
245 | sceneStyle: _reactNative.ViewPropTypes.style, 
246 | ...
```

...implicating ViewPropTypes is now undefined due to the react-native-web update.

--

Question: What is the approach to fixing these issues when a react-native-web (or other dependencies) dependency update causes an error in another dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from **@necolas** (`react-native-web` creator) on GitHub: "Read the release notes for each of the 6 minor version updates since `0.11` and take action accordingly:
https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/releases

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible solution / Quick fix

The above error can be solve by removing any `ViewPropTypes` usage from the library, or by mocking `ViewPropTypes` functionality whenever `ViewPropTypes` is `undefined`.

For example, the following fix has been solved the above error in `Router.js` (line 135) for my case:
`sceneStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : PropTypes.object`

This fix at `Router.js` seems to make `react-native-router-flux` function well with `react-native-web v0.12+`, but I don't sure if there are any more `ViewPropTypes` usage in the library.

However, mocking any `ViewPropTypes` usage with relevant `PropTypes` type will probably solve any issue like this

Source: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3707